# What is the best field validation plugin for Prototype?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, prototypejs

Not wanting to re-invent the wheel or anything, I was wondering if there's a plugin out there a field or form validation plugin that works with Prototype that you can recommend from your own experience and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Ben Keen's Really Simple Validation component.

Features I like:

All the validation rules can be kept within javascript so you're not adding class="required" to your HTML code.

You can display error messages in a javascript alert box or with HTML text.

Adding your own extensions is easy.

http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/

Note that I've only used the jQuery version, but a Prototype version is also available.

Comment: looks interesting, I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I like [wforms](http://www.formassembly.com/wForms/). Example:

```
<input type="text" name="myDate" class="validate-date"/>
```

Comment: ... this is not an example of wforms, just an input tag.

Comment: The class "validate-date" is automatically picked up and validated as a date when wforms is configured correctly.

Comment: That clarification could go in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[JSValidate](http://www.jsvalidate.com/)

Comment: although that looks like a fairly good plugin, I'm slightly worried by the fact that it's not been updated for a while.