# RSV Prototype Example

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to get Ben Keen's RSV for Prototype working. I found a [suggestion for Ben Keen's component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265541/what-is-the-best-field-validation-plugin-for-prototype) but, I'm having trouble getting it working with Prototype. Here is my code, it doesn't seem to be working. The error is RSV isn't a function. I'm not sure how to translate the [jQuery example](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/demo.php) to Prototype.

```
function DomLoaded() {
    var mainForm = document.forms[0];

    try {
        mainForm.RSV({
            onCompleteHandler: OnComplete,
            rules: ["required,txtEmailAddress,Please Enter an email addresss"]
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }

     alert("dom:loaded");
};

function OnComplete()
{
    alert("Complete.");

    //Stops Form from submitting
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this code myself. Here is the answer:

```
function DomLoaded() {
    try {
    var myRSV = new RSV({
        formID:"aspnetForm",
        onCompleteHandler: OnComplete,
        rules: ["required,txtEmailAddress,Please Enter an email addresss"]
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }

    alert("dom:loaded");
};

function OnComplete()
{
    alert("Complete.");

    //Stops Form from submitting
    return false;
}
```